# Connecting a windows pc to a harddrive stored in HDD bay enclosure connected to a mac

Tags: networking, windows-10, mac

I'm currently tasked on making a network for my office.
My office is doing video editing stuff and have 2 macs and 1 windows pc.
The plan is to have two usb 3.0 hdd bay connected to each macs, where the video and photo editing is done.
Then the windows PC would connect to the macs via network where it would access the files inside the bays, so that the people working on the windows pc could do their work.

The question is, how would I connect all those 3 computer? Because those drive will be removable. 
I was thinking about using FTP, because i heard macs own network share was kinda finicky on windows. But I don't know if you could give FTP access to a removable drive.

Comment: Don't use FTP, it's not the correct tool for the job. Use Windows file sharing (you can do it on Mac, but I don't have a Mac so can't advise how), or investigate NFS - which I expect a Mac will support, and you will be able to find Windows drivers for.

Comment: @davidgo interesting. I would definitely look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this, assuming you have a local area network, is to enable File Sharing on the Mac(s), which is via SMB, a protocol that any Windows machine will be able to connect to.

The method to enable this is:

1) Open System Preferences -> Sharing

2) Ensure that the checkbox is enabled next to File Sharing.

3) From there, ensure that the folder you want to share is enabled within the Shared Folders pane with the appropriate user privileges.

Comment: Yep, apparently it's as simple as that. Thank you very much!